# Creating an "anonymous enum" within a method (particularly in VB.NET)

Tags: .net, methods, enums, anonymous-types

I'd like to define an `enum` "on the fly" and use it as a parameter type for calling a method.  Is something like this possible?  Basically, I don't want to have to declare a class-level `enum` every time I have a method that needs one.

Here's how I would envision using it:

```
Function GetNumberOfLegs(ByVal ForAnimalType As <here's where I define my anonymous enum>) As Integer
    Select Case ForAnimalType
        Case Cat
            Return 4
        Case Human
            Return 2
    End Select
End Function
```

It seems reasonable that this should be possible, given that you can define anonymous types and use other related things like lambda expressions.

Comment: When you have a method that needs an `enum` you can't define your own - you must use the `enum` the function is using. Or I'm not getting something. Could you illustrate your issue with a code sample?

Comment: It'd be easy to answer if you can tell what you're trying to achieve. This sounds like a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @BartoszKP -- I'm the one creating the methods that are using the enums.  I'm looking for basically the ability to define an enum within the scope of the method so that when something calls the method, it can just provide a value with that enum type.

Comment: Right, I get it. Never heard of such a possibility. Consider that if your method does different things for different enum values it may be violating the Single Responsibility Principle, and often it might be better to just create N methods.

Comment: You can nest the enum inside a type (class or struct) but not inside the method scope. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel -- no, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Short answer: No, not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, basically. Well, you could use an `int` and some `const`s - but by the time you've done that, you might as well have used an `enum` (plus it will be much easier to work with).

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I've updated my question to make it clearer what I'm looking for.  If the answer is still "no", I'll accept that.

Comment: @roryap indeed, that doesn't exist. Worth asking, but nope.